# IIS Server MIME Error in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

everyone.

I built a very simple ASP.NET MVC application. It's working fine. When running from IIS Express in Visual Studio everything is normal.

I've published on IIS (Windows 10) and when I try to access the application I have a error in Dev Tools console:

```
GET http://localhost/Content/css/?v=TkaWEc0q1mz3K1xFKH7PU3OH3FTpfcRL8g5pn-9SziE1 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
```

I've checked my Network tab and found that there are two calls to Content/css and here's their headers:

[image: Request 1]
[image]

I've been doing some research about this issue and found that some solutions. So far:

My IIS has Static Contant configured
The MIME type for CSS in the IIS is text/css, even though the Content-Type in the header is text/html (which I don't understand why)

EDIT: As asked in the comments, here is my config bundle:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace IoTHub
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        { 
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/javascript").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/popper.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/iothub.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                      "~/Content/css/main.css",
                      "~/Content/css/common.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post line of codes config bundle?

Comment: Editted, @HienNguyen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

and check web.config set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="BundleModule" />
  <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
</modules>
```

Comment: It didn't work. I've made the changes, build, publish, restarted the server with these alterations and nothing different hapenned.

Comment: can you change from new StyleBundle("~/Content/css") to new StyleBundle("~/Content/styles"), and did you set compilation debug="false" ?

Comment: That last part did the trick. Thank you so much! This will be surely in my lessons learnt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your web config

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: It wasn't just that change that did it, but it helped! Thanks.